# Make a <div> dynamically fill the remainder of parent's height

Tags: css

Is it possible to make a div fill the remainder of a parent's height, after space has already been allocated to other elements?

Specifically, with the following layout:

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="sibling"></div>
  <div id="resizableDiv"></div>
</div>
```

The parent has a known, fixed height. However, the sibling is toggle-able, and may either have 0 height (`display: none`), or its normal height. The resizable div is the last child of the parent.

---

Can this be done:

- Dynamically, meaning that it updates when a previous sibling is shown or hidden; or inserted, removed; etc
- Without JavaScript?
- Without knowing the height of the other siblings in advance?
- For IE9 (extra credit)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible with CSS table and table-row.

http://jsfiddle.net/xs06asy9/

```js
$("button").click(function () {
    $("#resizableDiv").toggle();
});
```

```css
#parent {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}
#sibling, #resizableDiv {
    display: table-row;
    background: silver;
}
#resizableDiv {
    background: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
    <div id="sibling">1</div>
    <div id="resizableDiv">2</div>
</div>

<br/><button>Show/Hide</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried using [CSS3 flex-box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) model. I added flex properties to the `#parent` and it's children

```
#parent {
    height: 400px;
    border: 2px solid #333;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    align-items: stretch;
}
#sibling {
    border: 2px solid red;
    flex: 0 0 100px;
}
#resizableDiv {
    border: 2px solid green;
    flex: 1 0;
}
```

Please see working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kiirosora/u0a3u6y3/).

- No IE9 credits though :(

Comment: Well, that's what I have to look forward to when I can upgrade IE! :-) Thanks for the flex link.